# Finding Dimensions of a Vector Space of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

let $\Bbb{L}$ be the vector space of all linear operators $L: V \to V$, where $V$ is an n-dimensional vector space. Is there a way to find the dimension of $\Bbb{L}$ and if so how?

Comment: Can you solve this for a particular $n$-dimensional vector space?  The answer is independent of which $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ is used (why?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If you fix a basis of $V$, then there is a natural bijection between $\mathbb L$ and the space of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in whatever field you're working with, right?!

Comment: Im not sure I understand?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt Don't you know what's the connection between linear transformations and matrices?

Comment: yes you can write the linear transformation as a matrix. So L can be written as a $n \times n$ matrix

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt And what's the dimension of the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: $n^2$, so the dimension of $\Bbb{L}$ is $n^2$?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt Indeed!